# Specifying a Normal-Log-Normal Mixture (Skew Normal) in WINBUGS/JAGS

Tags: mixture-distribution, jags

I am an actuary working on a Bayesian loss reserve model using incremental average severity data. Exploratory analysis of the response seems to suggest a skew normal distribution of some sort would be appropriate, as there are some negative values in the left tail, and the log transformed positive values fit a normal distribution fairly well. I was inspired by [this posting](http://www.casact.org/newsletter/index.cfm?fa=viewart&id=6544) by Glenn Meyers and feel like the latter parameterization should be easy to implement in JAGS. However, since I am not used to JAGS, I am struggling to set the model up. Here is a example of what I am trying to do.

```
#Likelihood (training set)

for (i in 1:n){

  y[i] ~ dnorm(z[i], tau)

  z[i] ~ dlnorm(mu[i], tauln)

  mu[i] <- beta1*Dev[i] + ... 

}
```

I am not sure how to handle the negative $\mu_i$s in the absence of control structures (`if`, `else`, etc...) I am used to. I need to pass the zero valued or negative $\mu_i$s directly to the mean parameter for my response *y*<sub>i</sub>.
Is there a clever way to do this with the step function? Should I consider specifying the normal-log-normal mixture another way?
FYI – I also posted this question [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610036/thread/9061a96e/).

Comment: How about adding `mu_y[i] <- ifelse(mu[i] <= 0, mu[i], z[i])` and changing the stochastic node for `y` to `y[i] ~ dnorm(mu_y[i], tau)`?

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I wasn't aware there was a `ifelse` statement available in JAGS. Does this seem theoretically sound? I think originally I was confusing myself and assuming my `mu[i]` node was the expected value rather than the scale parameter.

Comment: The mixture above will produce a skewed distribution with a long positive tail, and seems reasonable if the values of `mu` are not too extreme. I suggest you fit the model, simulate a new response, and check the simulations against your observed data to see if they match. You can implement this 'posterior predictive check' via JAGS by adding an 'unobserved' response node to your model with the same parameters as the observed response.. for example `y_sim[i] ~ dnorm(mu_y[i], tau)`

Comment: And yes, your `mu` parameter is the log-scale and not the expected value.